# Excel find list of non blank cell address

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: screenshot of what I want]

Right now I wanted to collect all those non blank cell on B1:B7. I'm able to do that with

`={IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$7,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$7<>"",ROW($$B$1:$B$7)),ROW(1:1))),"")}`

The result is in column D.

However I need to try to get the address or row of the return reference. Which is shown in E and F.
Because my final goal is to get the car plate number. Which is shown in column G.

If the repair Status value would be unique, I could have used `index` and `match` to get the cell location. But... The value is not unique.

Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your solution. Tried that, but I have to refresh every time when I make changes to it.
and the actual excel sheet is much more complicated, with data from all across the month. Pivot table can't really do it as beautifully.

I realised I can just use

```
SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$7<>"",ROW($$B$1:$B$7)),ROW(1:1)))
```

to get the column number. From there it is enough for me to reference back to the vehicle number!
Thank you so much still!

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. (I corrected the double `$$` and the extra `)`'s.)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without any formulas, using a pivot table. Drag the repair status into the rows area, the vehicle number underneath the repair status and filter to remove blanks from repair status.

[image]